# configuration django with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, static, gunicorn

I have configured gunicorn on my server to run my django-backend.
It work's fine but it looks very bad. I can see my backend but it's only in HTML. No css etc like before. So I'm going to:

`mysite.com:9000` (I choose this port for my gunicorn-configuration)

I read I had to configure my django with nginx too. So I've installed it and told my django project the following (in settings.py):

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

After that I'm going to my folder on my server where the project is build. I'm activating my venv and doing the following command.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

It creates a static-folder in my project with all the necessary files.

The problem is the configuration with nginx. I really need it on mysite:9000
Not on mysite:900/static or something. I don't know how to configure it.
This was what I've tried.

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
sudo nano test


server {
        server_name mysite.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/myproject/static/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Than I went to

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

and did the following command and restarted nginx.

```
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/myproject
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going to the wrong URL. You've configured gunicorn to run on port 9000, but nginx is running as the reverse proxy on the default web port, which is the whole point of it. You should just be going to mysite.com; nginx will proxy the Django app to :9000 and serve the assets directly.

Comment: But there is something else running at the moment on mysite.com. Is it not possible to get the static files on the mysite.com:9000? It's just for a better interface of my backend.

Comment: Then you should set up nginx on a different port, or a different virtual host.

Comment: Okay, But when you don't configure nginx than it's normal that gunicorn is shown in pure html? (functionality of it is fine)

Comment: Yes, because Django doesn't serve the assets itself.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird. So you can access on port 9000 the gunicorn (in pure html) and on another port you will see the gunicorn with the nginx (with the right layout)

Comment: But your port 9000 won't be exposed outside your local machine: gunicorn is only bound to the localhost address, it's nginx that is responsible for making that available to the outside world.

Comment: Okay Now I'm running it on another port (3000) It all looks fine now. But in mysite:3000 I see reference to my models like this: "company": "http://mysite:9000/company/". So when i'm clicking on it I'm going to the ugly site. When I'm manually doing mysite:3000/company it works and looks fine. But I want to change the references in my indexpage from port 9000 to port 3000.

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration with `collectstatic` will serve the static files through django, hence on http://:9000/static.

The most efficient way to serve the files on a different port is directly through nginx. You can have multiple `server` directives in nginx.conf, each with its own `listen` directive.

See the answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/242679/how-to-run-multiple-nginx-instances-on-different-port